# meta Refreshing a page with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Obviously you can refresh with meta refresh and javascript, but i think jquery would be more reliable because the other methods i listed sometimes freezes. How is this coded?

Comment: JQuery is just a javascript library/framework...  so jQuery can't be more reliable than javascript

Comment: I think the author means in terms of cross-browser compatibility etc, but in this case that is a moot point as it's very simple code.

Answer (score 1):

Using location.reload() to reload the page.. you can wrap it with a timer such that it refreshes after 5 seconds..

You don't need jQuery for this.. Below plain javascript will do the work.

```
<script>
   (function () {
      setTimeout(function () { 
         window.location.reload(); 
      }, 5000);
    })();
 </script>
```

Comment: yea sometimes it freezes when i leave it alone. I have 6 tabs open on chrome and it will sometimes freeze when i'm not viewing the tab.

Comment: @jtayler - Make sure you have it like above, if it still freezes.. then there must be something else that would be causing the problem... Do not add any scripts inside the enclosed script tag.

Answer (score 1):

Because page reloading is such basic and well supported javascript, jQuery doesn't have a magic way of doing it. A couple of ways in javascript are:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href;
```

or

```
window.location.reload();
```

The freezing on your page is almost certainly caused by some other piece of code. Can you post your example?

Comment: it freezes when i leave it alone , sometimes. What I want is the most reliable way of refreshing a page.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can refresh a page by using:

```
location.reload()
```

Comment: This is just normal JavaScript, and does not require jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The page can be refreshed easily with:

```
location.reload()
```

And also combined with setTimeout should you require a delay before refreshing the page

```
setTimeout(function(){
    location.reload();
}, 1000)
```

None of this requires jQuery :)